# Как проверить, что user ввел символы пробела в input?

Tags: javascript

Всем привет. Я делаю проверку вводимых данных пользователем в форму. Одно из условий, как вы понимаете, строка не должна состоять из пробелов, ибо пустое ненужно поле появляется. Я хочу сделать такую функцию:

```
function checkInput (text_from_input) {
   return true ore false
```

}

Если запись будет состоять целиком из пробелов, то функция вернет значение false и поле не пройдет проверку, и я закрашу все в красный цвет. Но вот что написать в теле функции, я не знаю. Подскажите, как проверить на вводимые пробелы и вывести false в этом случае.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
// ecma 6

const CheckSpaces = (str) => str.trim() !== '';

console.log(CheckSpaces('     '));
console.log(CheckSpaces(''));
console.log(CheckSpaces('  1 '));

// ecma 5


function CheckSpaces2(str) {
  return str.trim() !== '';
}

console.log(CheckSpaces2('     '));
console.log(CheckSpaces2(''));
console.log(CheckSpaces2('  1 '));
```

Comment: огромное спасибо

Answer (score 3):

```
function checkInput (text_from_input) {
   return /[^\s]/gim.test(text_from_input);
}
```

Comment: Расскажите, чем Ваш ответ отличается от моего функционально? (Это сугубо интерес)

Comment: @Vyacheslav Potseluyko, ничем, этот RegExp так же ищет "есть ли в строке какие-то символы кроме пробельных". Если есть отдает true, если нет false. Ну точнее ваш вырезает, и проверяет осталось ли что-то, а мой просто проверяет есть ли что-то.

Comment: спасибо за пояснения:)

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

$(".click").click(function(){
var input_str=$(".inp").val();

if (input_str.indexOf(' ') > -1)
{
  alert("Есть пробел");
}else{
  alert("Нет пробела");
}
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="inp" type="text">

<a href="#" class="click">ClickMe</a>
```

Comment: Такой вариант не отреагирует на остальные пробельные символы, что вряд ли подходит автору

Comment: спасибо большое

Comment: @andreymal видимо автору вообще без разницы))

Comment: @Cheg без разницы автору, а разбираться с качеством ответов на SO нам :(

Comment: Да ладно, чего вы, потыкается потыкается, поймет, что что-то не так, придет снова )

Comment: @MedvedevDev до проверки табуляции, может, додуматься ещё можно, а вот переноса строки или неразрывного пробела уже маловероятно, а про ZERO-WIDTH SPACE наверно вообще всего три с половиной читателя википедии слышали))

Answer (score 1):

В вашем случае лучше обойтись без javascript. Правильнее будет составить regexp для всех ваших условий и сделать его паттерном для input-тега.

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" pattern="[\w]{1,15}" placeholder="Введите слово" title="Латиницей и без пробелов!" required="required">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Неправда. Такой вариант не позволяет изменять стили ошибок.

Comment: @VyacheslavPotseluyko вопрос был не о стилях. Если вам нужно по-своему обработать ошибку, вы можете в атрибутах onvalid и oninvalid указать нужные вам функции.